# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' in D:\Training\todolist-v1\views\list.ejs while compiling ejs

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

Still on my learning curve and ran into the following problem:

## SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' in D:\Training\todolist-v1\views\list.ejs while compiling ejs

```
<body>

    <ul>

            <% for (var i=0; i<newListItems.length; i++) { %>
                <li><%= newListItems[i] %></li>
            <% } %>

    </ul>

    <!-- CREATING A FORM -->

    <form action="/" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="Enter item to do ">
        <button type="submit" name="button">Add Item</button>
    </form>

</body>
```

the app.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

let items = ["Take kids to school", "Go to gym", "Go shopping"];

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {

  let today = new Date();

  var options = {
    weekday: "long",
    day: "numeric",
    month: "long"
  };
  let day = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);

  res.render("list", {
    kindOfDay: day,
    newListItems: items
  });
});


app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  let item = req.body.newItem;
  items.push(item);
  res.redirect("/");
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Server started on PORT 3000");
});
```

The Error Message that I get

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' in D:\Training\todolist-v1\views\list.ejs while compiling ejs

If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at Template.compile (D:\Training\todolist-v1\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:673:12)
    at Object.compile (D:\Training\todolist-v1\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:398:16)
    at handleCache (D:\Training\todolist-v1\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:235:18)
    at tryHandleCache (D:\Training\todolist-v1\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:274:16)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (D:\Training\todolist-v1\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:10)
    at View.render (D:\Training\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (D:\Training\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:657:10)
    at Function.render (D:\Training\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:609:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (D:\Training\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
```

Thanks, I'm curious to know

I try to update the to do list using the array to hold my collection items, but what I get is the error message below:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' in D:\Training\todolist-v1\views\list.ejs while compiling ejs

Comment: Does the error message say which line number this error happens on? Is it the `for` loop line, for sure?

Comment: What's the reason for the backslash in your `<body>` tag?

Comment: Also, you realize you're commenting out the entirety of the end of this line, including the closing curly brace and parenthesis, right?
`app.post("/", function (req, res) {//item =`

Comment: I've been able to make it cleaner, some comments were making it confusing to understand the code. 
That's exactly my code and I keep getting the error message of unexpected token. Thanks